# Reducing lengthy ASP.Net MVC Controller methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a controller method that performs the following actions:

1. Loads information from database
2. Performs some logic checks
3. Moves files around
4. Updates information in the database
5. Automatically sends emails to a (potentially) large number of recipients

This method is taking a long time to complete and I believe the emailing at the end of the process is mostly to blame. I cannot return success/failure to the user until after step 4 has successfully completed.

In order to speed up the page response times, I'd like to actually return a response to the user *before* step 5 starts, as the user doesn't really need to know the result of step 5.

My first idea was to make two controller methods, and have the client automatically hit the second method when it got a result from the first one - but I'd rather not put this logic into the hands of the client.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: put email functionality in an async method and return after you've called that method

Comment: Also you can call the send email function inside a parallel foreach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QueueBackgroundWorkItem in the 5th step in your action to queue the email work then return to client immediately.

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(e =>
{
    SendEmail();
});
```